# Looking for conflicting records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Server table

```
Meetings:
-Id,
-RoomId,
-DataFrom,
-DataTo
```

I would like to get all meetings which has any collision.
There is an example:

```
Meeting 1:
Id: 1,
RoomId: 1,
DataFrom: 1 P.M
DataTo: 3 P.M

Meeting 2:
Id: 2
Room: 1,
DataFrom: 2.P.M
DataTo: 3 P.M
```

There is a collision because the room is the same and the second meeting is set during the first one.

I need also point the Id of conflicting object.
How to do it, by view or function?

Comment: Is `DataFrom` and `DataTo` datetime fields?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH MEETINGS(ID,ROOMID,DATAFROM,DATATO) AS
(
   SELECT 1,1,'20210421 13:00','20210421 15:00'
     UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,1,'20210421 14:00','20210421 15:00'
)
SELECT M.ID ,M.ROOMID,M.DATAFROM,M.DATATO,M2.ID AS CONFLICTED_ID
FROM MEETINGS  AS M
JOIN MEETINGS AS M2 ON M.ROOMID=M2.ROOMID
AND (M.DATAFROM BETWEEN M2.DATAFROM AND M2.DATATO OR
    M.DATATO BETWEEN M2.DATAFROM AND M2.DATATO)
AND M.ID<>M2.ID
```

Could you please try the above

Comment: I think between is not correct! If one meeting start from 1 till 3 then another meeting start from 3 to 5 in the same room, your query will take it as an collision, am I right?

Comment: I guess, yes. Your solution with >= and < looks better

Answer (score 1):

We have two periods (p1 and p2), this two periods will conflict with each other if p1.start be between of p2.start and p2.end, or p2.start be between p1.start and p1.end. (I suggest draw two lines as a period on a paper and simulate what I explained)

note: There is a tricky point, we can't use between syntax, because if we have tow meetings, one started from 1 to 3 another started from 3 to 5, in a same room, these two are not conflicted, but between will take it as a conflict so we have to use `<=` and `<`

```
select
   m1.Id m1_Id,m2.Id m2_Id,m1.RoomId,
   case
      when m1.DataForm <= m2.DataForm then m2.DataForm
      else m1.DataForm
   end collision_start,
   case
      when m1.DataForm <= m2.DataForm then m1.DataTo
      else m2.DataTo
   end collision_end
from Meetings m1
inner join Meetings m2 on m1.Id<>m2.Id and m1.RoomId=m2.RoomId
where
   (m1.DataForm <= m2.DataForm and m2.DataForm < m1.DataTo)
   or
   (m2.DataForm <= m1.DataForm and m1.DataForm < m2.DataTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the job

```
SELECT M1.ID, M2.ID
FROM MEETINGS M1
CROSS JOIN MEETINGS M2
WHERE M1.ID != M2.ID 
AND M1.DATAFROM > M2.DATAFROM 
AND M1.DATAFROM < M2.DATATO
ORDER BY M1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Two meetings overlap if one starts *before* the second ends and the first ends *after* the first starts.

To get all meetings that overlap, you can use `exists`:

```
select m.*
from meetings m
where exists (select 1
              from meetings m2
              where m2.roomid = m.roomid and
                    m2.datafrom < m.datato and
                    m2.datato > m.datafrom
             )
order by roomid, datafrom;
```

If you want all pairs of overlapping meetings, then use:

```
select m.*, m2.*
from meetings m join
     meetings m2
     on m2.roomid = m.roomid and
        m2.datafrom < m.datato and
        m2.datato > m.datafrom
order by m.roomid, m.datafrom;
```

Note that this gets all overlaps.  Some are tricky, such as:

```
A---B-----B---A
```